# Script to check output of a command and fail or pass jenkins build based on a parameter

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that runs a policy check on yaml files and returns a deny message if there is and error. I want to write a script for the job to fail if a deny message is returned.

This is the command:

```
opa exec "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/open-policy-agent-test/" --config-file=/home/isw_user/opa-conf.yaml --decision /rules
```

This is the result of the command:

```
    {
  "result": [
    {
      "path": "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/open-policy-agent-test/atlantis.yaml",
      "result": {
        "deny": []
      }
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/open-policy-agent-test/manifest/samplefour.yaml",
      "result": {
        "deny": []
      }
    },
    {
      "path": "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/open-policy-agent-test/test.yaml",
      "result": {
        "deny": [
          "Wrong"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So if the deny command contains any message I want the build to fail.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can simply execute a command and return the `STDOUT`. If you are returning a JSON, you can even parse the Json and extract whatever value you want and validate. Please refer to the following sample. Please note the `returnStdout: true` to return the output of the command.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def output = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "opa exec "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/open-policy-agent-test/" --config-file=/home/isw_user/opa-conf.yaml --decision /rules").trim()
                    if (output != "") { // Do any validation here
                        error "Build Has Errors, Failing" 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```